# File Scanner skipping over line

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

At my school we have been tasked with coding a "perfect game of battle ship". To do this we are given a file, ships.txt, which we must scan and look for any ships, A, P, B, S, or C, and print out their locations. This is the file(10x10):

```
..CCC.....
..........
...A.....B
...A.SSS.B
...A.....B
...A......
..........
.......PP.
..........
..........
```

Here is the code that i have:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class BattleShip{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        Scanner scf = new Scanner(new File("ships.txt"));
        String line = "p";

        for(int c = 0; c<10;c++){
            line = scf.nextLine() + " ";

            for(int h = 0;h<10;h++){

                boolean isShip =          line.substring(h,h+1).equalsIgnoreCase(".");
                if(isShip == false){
                    System.out.println(c + "," + h);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the answers are:

```
(0,2)
(0,3)
(0,4)
(2,3)
(2,9)
(3,3)
(3,5)
(3,6)
(3,7)
(3,9)
(4,3)
(4,9)
(5,3)
(5,9)
(6,3)
(8,7)
(8,8)
```

The problem is that Eclipse prints out:

```
(0,2)
(0,3)
(0,4)
(2,3)
(2,9)
(3,3)
(3,5)
(3,6)
(3,7)
(3,9)
(4,3)
(4,9)
(5,3)
(7,7)
(7,8)
```

My best guess is that the scanner is skipping the 5th line but for the life of me i can not figure out why or how to fix it. Can someone please help?

Comment: You should double-check your expected output. And remember, your code works **0-based** (loop-indices)!

Comment: Your program is printing out the correct coordinates.  What you "know" the answers are looks incorrect.

Comment: It is almost right but 1) there should be 17 outputs bc there are 17 ships and 2) there are no ships on the 7th row the patrol boat (PP) is on the 8th row, and finally 3) 0 is the first row and column.

Comment: There are 15 letters here.  The patrol boat is definitely on the 7th row.  Top row is 0, bottom row is 9.

Answer (score 0):

With a little tweak to the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class BattleShip{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        Scanner fileScanner= new Scanner(new File("ships.txt"));
        String line;

        for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++){
            line = fileScanner.nextLine() + " ";

            for(int column = 0; column < 10; column++){

                boolean isShip = line.substring(column, column + 1).equalsIgnoreCase(".");

                if(isShip == false){
                    System.out.print(row + "," + column + "\t");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(".\t");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        fileScanner.close();
    }
}
```

you'll get the following output:

```
.   .   0,2 0,3 0,4 .   .   .   .   .   
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   
.   .   .   2,3 .   .   .   .   .   2,9 
.   .   .   3,3 .   3,5 3,6 3,7 .   3,9 
.   .   .   4,3 .   .   .   .   .   4,9 
.   .   .   5,3 .   .   .   .   .   .   
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   7,7 7,8 .   
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
```

it's basically the same code logic, just added some line breaks, dots and tabs here and there to make it look clearer.

Obviously, the output is correct, and no lines are being skipped.

The answers you were given seem to be wrong, not eclipse :p